# could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[String]

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to load a dataframe into a Hive table.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode
import org.apache.spark.sql._

object SparkToHive {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val warehouseLocation = "file:${system:user.dir}/spark-warehouse"
    val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder.master("local[2]").appName("Saving data into HiveTable using Spark")
                        .enableHiveSupport()
                        .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true")
                        .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict")
                        .config("hive.metastore.warehouse.dir", "/user/hive/warehouse")
                         .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouseLocation)
                        .getOrCreate()
    **import sparkSession.implicits._**
    val partfile = sparkSession.read.text("partfile").as[String]

    val partdata = partfile.map(part => part.split(","))
    case class Partclass(id:Int, name:String, salary:Int, dept:String, location:String)
    val partRDD  = partdata.map(line => PartClass(line(0).toInt, line(1), line(2).toInt, line(3), line(4)))
    val partDF   = partRDD.toDF()
    partDF.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).insertInto("parttab")
  }
}
```

I haven't executed it yet but I am getting the following error at this line:

```
import sparkSession.implicits._
could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[String]
```

How can I fix this ?

Comment: works fine for me in Spark 2.1  after moving case class out of main method

Comment: can you try adding `.rdd` in front of `.map`? in my case that cast was needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake I made was

1. Case class should be outside the main and inside the object
2. In this line: `val partfile =    sparkSession.read.text("partfile").as[String]`, I used       `read.text("..")` to get a file into Spark where we can use       `read.textFile("...")`

Comment: great going. I am happy to have helped you sort it out :)

Comment: Why is this marked as answer and not @RameshMaharjan ?

Answer (score 16):

Please move your `case` `class` `Partclass` outside of `SparkToHive` object. It should be fine then

And there are `**` in you `implicits import` statement. Try

```
import sparkSession.sqlContext.implicits._
```

Comment: Did this:
case class partc(id:Int, name:String, salary:Int, dept:String, location:String)
object SparkToHive {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
  . . . . . . .
}
}
But still getting the error.

Comment: there are ** in you implicits import statement. Try `import sparkSession.sqlContext.implicits._`

Comment: I tried to give them a BOLD appearance. Thats why you see **. In the program, i don't have any.

Comment: Ok :) did you try as I said ?

Comment: yes. Error has moved to this line.
    val partfile = sparkSession.read.text("partfile").as[String]
Message: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[String]

Comment: why don't you read it as `val partfile = sparkSession.sparkContext.textFile("partfile")`. And you should be fine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147695/discussion-between-sidhartha-and-ramesh-maharjan).